# How could we show that $s_n=2e^{-n}$, if $n$ is even and $-\frac{3}{n}$ when $n$ is odd, converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How could we show that $s_n=2e^{-n}$, if $n$ is even and $-\frac{3}{n}$ when $n$ is odd, converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Using only the definition of convergence. So what I have tried is finding n for both the odd and even cases and concluding from the definition of convergence that they both converge and so s_n must converge. However, in the solutions I have seen that maximum of both of the n's has been taken, I am struggling to understand why.

Comment: Note that $|s_n|\le \frac{3}{n}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV   How does this help?

Comment: Because 3/n -> 0.  so |s_n| <= 3/n so s_n-> 0.

Comment: $$|s_n|\le \frac3n<\epsilon$$whenever $n>N=\lfloor \frac3{\epsilon}\rfloor +1$

Comment: What exactly do you mean "the maximum of both the n has be taken".  The n's tend to infinity so they have no max.  Do you mean the max of the N's such that n > N1 assure the |s_n|;even  < eps and n>N2 assure that |s_n|;odd < eps.  In that case you take the max of N1 and N2 to assure that the n you choose is bigger than both.  if you do N1 < n < N2 then it's possible |s_n|;even < eps but |s_n|;odd > eps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and choose an integer $N$ with $N>\max\{\ln\frac{2}{\epsilon},\frac{3}{\epsilon}\}$.

If $n\ge N$, then

1) for $n$ even, $n\ge N>\ln\frac{2}{\epsilon}\implies e^n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}\implies|s_n|=\frac{2}{e^n}<\epsilon$

2) for $n$ odd, $n\ge N>\frac{3}{\epsilon}\implies|s_n|=\frac{3}{n}<\epsilon$.

Therefore $|s_n|<\epsilon$ if $n\ge N$.

---

(As Dr. MV points out, the proof could be simplified using that $\max\{\ln\frac{2}{\epsilon},\frac{3}{\epsilon}\}=\frac{3}{\epsilon}$)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is taken because you then get a $N$ such that all elements $s_n$ satisfy $|s_n|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Do you mind showing me you would do it with the max ?

Comment: $s_n;n odd \rightarrow 0$.  so for eps > 0 there is an N such that n > N => |sn;n odd| < eps.  But maybe |sn; n even| > eps.  What then?  $s_n;even \rightarrow 0$ so for eps > 0 there is an M such that n > M => |sn: n even < eps.  But maybe |sn; n odd| > eps.  What then?  Well if n > max(M, N) then n > M  **AND** n > N so |s_n| < eps whether n is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it  you to show $t_n = 2e^{-n} \rightarrow 0$ and $r_n = -3/n \rightarrow 0$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N_1$ so that $n \ge N_1$ $|t_n| < \epsilon$.

Likewise there is an $N_2$ so that $n \ge N_2$ $|r_n| < \epsilon$.

So for $N_3 = \max(N_1, N_2)$ if $n \ge N_3$ then $|s_n| \le \max(|r_n|, |t_n|) < \epsilon$.

So $s_n \rightarrow 0$.

=======

Or to make a more general result:

If $\{s_n\}$ consists solely of subsequences that all converge to the same point, $c$ ... that is, if $\{s_n\} = \cup_{i=1...m}\{s_{i_n}\}$ and $\{s_{i_n}\}\rightarrow  c$... then $\{s_n\}\rightarrow c$.

Proof:  For any $\epsilon > 0$, by definition of convergence, there exist several $N_i$ such that $n > N_i$ implies  that $|s_{i_n} - c|<\epsilon$.  Let $\overline{N} = \max\{N_i\}$.  So $ n > \overline{N}$ implies that $n > N_i$ for every $i$.  So $|s_n - c| < \epsilon$.  Which is the definition of $\{s_n\}\rightarrow c$.

So why did we do $\overline{N} = \max\{N_i\}$?  Because if we didn't we could have situation where $N_i < n < N_j$ and $s_n \in \{s_{j_m}\};s_n \not \in \{s_{i_m}\}$ and $|s_n - c| > \epsilon$ and we get nowhere.  But if $n > \max \{N_i\}$ then $n > N_i$ for *all* $i$ and such can never happen.

So here we have $t_{2n} = 2e^{2n}\rightarrow 0$ and $r_{2n+1} = -3/(2n+1)\rightarrow $ and $s_n = \{t_{2n}\}\cup \{r_{2n+1}\}$ so $s_n \rightarrow 0$.